# indentationLevel property doesn't appear to do anything?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I'm have a number rows I'm inserting into a table using -insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation, and I would like the rows to be indented from the left to distinguish them from the rest of the cells. The indentationLevel property of UITableViewCell looks like it's exactly what I need, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Here's the code I'm using to set the indentation level (dot syntax doesn't make a difference):

```
[cell setIndentationWidth:10];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];
```

Is indentationLevel what I want, or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 14):

indentationLevel and indentationWidth affect the positioning of the standard items textLabel, detailTextLabel, and imageView. They do not affect the origin of contentView's frame.

If you are not using textLabel, etc. (perhaps because targeting iPhone OS 2), you need to handle the indentation manually, as the previous answer shows.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 7 if you are not using custom cells.

Setting either `indentationLevel` or `indentationWidth` within `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` has no effect on the cell's layout when it is time to display it.

For example, consider the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    BOOL isIndented = indexPath.row % 2;

    cell.textLabel.text = isIndented ? @"Indented" : @"Not indented";
    cell.indentationLevel = isIndented;
}
```

I don't have enough reputation to post screenshots, but the result is different between iOS 6 and iOS 7. This is using Xcode 5 and the iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: The workaround is to use a custom cell, even if it is to emulate a default cell style. Just create a new subclass of UITableViewCell and depending on whether you are using Storyboards or Nib files, configure a prototype cell or register a Nib file respectively for use by your cell subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue with my app. I had a `UITableView` that was NOT using custom cells. I was using a `UITableViewCell` with a Basic style. In my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method I set the cell's `indentationWidth` and `indentationLevel`. They did nothing. I even tried modifying the `- (NSInteger)tableView: indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. Nothing.

What did eventually work was going to the storyboard and modifying the attributes of the Table View Cell itself. Once I set the Indentation Width there, I started getting proper indentation. The `indentationLevel` property started to work. Even the `- (NSInteger)tableView: indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` was useful.

Basically, it looks like the `indentationWidth` property is ignored in favour of the "Indentation Width" in the storyboard.

This was with Xcode 5.0.2 targeting iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've read suggests that's how you're supposed to do it.  Make sure that you aren't creating a new cell with the same pointer later on in the code (after you set the indentation, but before it gets drawn).  Have you tried setting the indentation to something larger that would be more noticeable on the screen (say, 100px instead of 10)?

Comment: When you say pointer, you aren't referring to the identifier, are you? My cells are all objects from the same class, so I imagine they would all be pointers to the same object. My cell identifier, however, is based on the full indexPath, and is therefore unique for each cell. Still no joy for indenting, though.

Comment: I've confirmed that the indentation level and width are being set in the cell before the cell is returned to the OS for display. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-riding its implementation in your cells. 
in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        if (cell == nil) 
        { 
            cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"cellType01"] autorelease]; 
            [cell setIndentationLevel:indexPath.row];
            [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            // Tag the view 
            [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:111]; 
            UILabel* labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(cell.indentationLevel*cell.indentationWidth, 0, 300, 20)]; 
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 4 years old, but if you are **already** using a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, **and** you're already adding your views as subviews of `contentView` make sure you're not overriding `layoutSubviews` in your cell. If you are, you'll need to adjust the bounds/center or frame of the contentView manually, in `layoutSubviews`.